# What's the better way to addObserver/removeObserver with NSNotificationCenter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I used to `addObserver` in `viewDidLoad:` and `removeObserver` in `dealloc:`. Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(refreshData)
                                                 name:AnyNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:AnyNotification
                                                  object:nil];
}
```

But according to some articles said, it's better to `addObserver` in `viewDidAppear:` and `removeObserver` in `viewDidDisappear:`. Code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(refreshData)
                                                 name:AnyNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:AnyNotification
                                                  object:nil];
}
```

So, what's the better way to addObserver/removeObserver?

Comment: It's not good to remove an observer in `dealloc` in case of possible memory warning happening.

Comment: In view did disappear, just make sure you remove observer for each specific notification and not removeObserver:self or else you remove the super classes notification observers when the view reappears.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

this depends on your scenario, usually the best approach is to add in `viewDidLoad` and remove in `dealloc` and in `viewDidUnload` (deprecated in iOS 9.0, use `dealloc` only), but there are some cases when you have same method in different classes like UI effects and want to call only current screen's method using notification, then you will have to add the observer in `viewWillAppear` and remove it in `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidAppear`/`viewDidDisappear`

**Edit:**
A note from comments, thanks @honey.

Though now since iOS 9, you no longer need to care about removing the observer. See [Apple release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-FoundationOlderNotes/index.html#X10_11Notes): "In OS X 10.11 and iOS 9.0 NSNotificationCenter and NSDistributedNotificationCenter will no longer send notifications to registered observers that may be deallocated..

Comment: I think the first solution is not the best because there can be situations when class was inited but the view was not loaded. App will crash with error "Cannot remove an observer <CustomViewController 0xbbc19c0> for the key path "KEY_PATH" from <OBJ 0x111bc890> because it is not registered as an observer."

Comment: @DanSkeel maybe add in `init` and `awakeFormNib`?

Comment: WHY best to add in `viewDidLoad`, rather than in `viewWillAppear`?  I don't see the benefit.  I prefer to keep the observer around only while it is needed, so I use `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear`. Also, those calls seem to be reliably paired.

Comment: Well if you need to update some date in rootviewcontroller or any viewcontroller prior to current view controller in stack, your notification will not fired to the previous view controller if you use viewWillAppear/Disappear. As mentioned in Question, it depends on Scenario

Comment: @DanSkeel if you have such a scenario where that's possible then it likely means `viewDidLoad` isn't the place you should write the observer. Each business/UI requirement should have its own appropriate cycle. Though now **since iOS 9**, you no longer need to care about removing the observer. See [Apple release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-FoundationOlderNotes/index.html): "In OS X 10.11 and iOS 9.0 NSNotificationCenter and NSDistributedNotificationCenter will no longer send notifications to registered observers that may be deallocated..."

Comment: @Saad - thanks, that is a useful point to know. I had not thought about the order that events occur, when considering a view plus the preceding view.

Comment: Just a friendly note here that viewDidUnload was deprecated in iOS 6. Therefore in more recent code you need to use a different site to balance your Add/Remove observer calls.  Indeed, after iOS 9, removeObserver is not always required.

Answer (score 5):

I would normally put it in `-viewDidAppear:` and `-viewDidDisapear:` (or `-viewWillAppear:` and `-viewWillDisappear:`) simply because in every case I came across I'm only interested in the notification if the view is actually displayed.

It's probably a premature optimisation (your code for handling the notification could take some time, but might be useless if the view is not displayed), but then it's also no more code - it's the same code just in a different method...

Comment: This is the correct approach because the view can sometimes be loaded and not immediately appear on screen, like when implementing UIStateRestoring. And you can make use if isMovingToParentViewController inside viewWillAppear to only do things once.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial. I use it with viewWillAppear/viewWillDisappear so my UI is always up-do-date, even if I hide that view controller, saving resources because I will not update it until is shown again.

Answer (score 0):

`-viewWillAppear:` + `-viewWillDisappear:` is better than `-viewDidAppear:` + `-viewDidDisapear:`, because they are always called the same number of times.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve ,they are paired.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve , when navigation controller's `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` is enabled.

Comment: OK, I understand what you are saying now. I've edited your wording to make it clearer, and upvoted you, as I believe you are making an important point. [Though I'm not currently developing an app, so I can't confirm that the `Did` functions are not always balanced.] (Someone else must have downvoted you, perhaps for the same reason I was confused - couldn't tell what you were saying.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve , (o^^o) I know. But I can't express accurately, because of my poor English writing.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach using NSNotifications is **adding the observer when you need to observe for notifications** and **remove them when you don't need them anymore**.

This could be on `viewDidLoad:`, `viewWillAppear:`, or when the user taps some button etc.

I will give you a little example:

My app has a tabbar, and in some of the view controllers, I'm displaying some info downloaded from internet (a tweet for example). I also have a class pooling for new data from server each 2 minutes, and as the server had new data, I updated the info on database. I will not use a delegate pattern to listen to DB changes, because I have so many view controllers displaying data, and it will be a very bad design making the delegate an array and looping to pass the data for every view controller. So, in this specific scenario, the best to do is to post a notification telling every VC that new data has come.

If your VC removes the delegate when the view disappears, only the current one will receive the notification and update the displaying contents.

You obviously could update the contents of the other VCs before display, on `viewWillAppear:` for example, but doing this the VC contents will be updated not only when necessary, but each time you change tabs.

It was only one example, where I tried to show you that for NSNotifications, is difficult to advise you when to add or remove observers when we don't have the entire description of how you app behaviours.