# Add MFMessageComposeViewControllerTextMessageAvailabilityDidChange notification

Tags: ios, swift, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I want to set MFMessageComposeViewControllerTextMessageAvailabilityDidChange notification to observer. I am new to swift so, i am not clear about how to do that. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift 3.0

```
 let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default // Note that default is now a property, not a method call
 notificationCenter.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name(rawValue: MFMessageComposeViewControllerTextMessageAvailabilityDidChange),object: nil, queue: nil,using: catchNotification)

 //handle the notification fired method
 func catchNotification(notification: Notification) -> Void {

 }
```

Comment: where i add MFMessageComposeViewControllerTextMessageAvailabilityDidChange notification ?

Comment: add it in viewDidLoad method

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631375/whats-the-better-way-to-addobserver-removeobserver-with-nsnotificationcenter for better understanding of calling the addObserver. It depends on your requirement.

Comment: @ShariifIslam does the above helps?

Comment: Little bit, actually i add observer  successfully but **MFMessageComposeViewControllerTextMessageAvailabilityDidChange** not working properly.

Comment: can you explain your issue?

Comment: Also make sure you are sending the sms on device.

Comment: The original question posted is resolved. Now you have a different issue. Kindly upvote the answer if it helped and ask a different question for your current issue.

Comment: Are you doing this:- Upon receiving this notification, query its userInfo dictionary with the MFMessageComposeViewControllerTextMessageAvailabilityKey key. If the availability of text message sending has changed, your app should invalidate caches and update its user interface as appropriate.

Comment: Yes, i am trying to get notification if SMS failed. But this notification only fire if device is not capable to sending SMS or device is not configured for send SMS. So, if SMS failed due to insufficient balance then its not called.

Answer (score 1):

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourClass.yourFunction(notification:_)), name: Notification.Name.MFMessageComposeViewControllerTextMessageAvailabilityDidChange, object: nil)
```

Function:

```
func yourFunction(notification: Notification) { }
```

I have not tested yet! But it's should work. Let me know if it's works

Discussion

> Upon receiving this notification, query its userInfo dictionary with
>   the MFMessageComposeViewControllerTextMessageAvailabilityKey key. If
>   the availability of text message sending has changed, your app should
>   invalidate caches and update its user interface as appropriate.

From official documentation

Comment: No, its not working. Not getting notification when phone is on airplane mode or when Message app failed to send SMS.

Comment: I add this observer to 'viewWillAppear' - NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(changeByNotification(notification:)), name: Notification.Name.MFMessageComposeViewControllerTextMessageAvailabilityDidChange, object: nil)

and this is method declaration -
func changeByNotification(notification: Notification)
    {
        print("func called ....")
    }

Comment: What did you get on the console?

Comment: Ok! Another way: Remove the registered observer from the viewWillAppear and put it inside of MessageComposeResult's .failed case.

Comment: No, failed case not get called. Its call .sent  status and after called .sent case Message app failed to send SMS.